# Bind value to image dynamically in angular

Tags: angular, image, data-binding, qr-code, dynamic-binding

I am generating multi qr code image and need to bind `scr.Value` to image tag.The image doesn't show for me.Pls let me know any changes to be done to this line  `<img class='boxqrcode' [src]="'data:image/png;base64,' + {{scr.Value}}">`

```
<div class="Qrcodediv" *ngFor="let scr of sreenItemsList">
 <img class='boxqrcode' src="'data:image/png;base64,' + {{scr.Value}}">
</div>

  for (let i = 0; i < qr.Image.length; i++) {             
            var a = qr.Image[i]
            this.sreenItemsList.push(a);          
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried with `[src]="'data:image/png;base64,' + scr.Value"`? Also, check if it's really 'scr,Value' and not 'src.Value'.

Comment: Did you remove the {{ }} too?

Comment: Can you provide some code on stackblitz.com to replicate this ?